# Scale image proportionally within a div

Tags: image, css

I have an image area in which a random image will be visible. How do I make the image fit to its width or height within the image area while maintaining the image proportions?

[image]

This is what I tried, but it distorts the image:

```
<div style="float:right;"> <!-- img area -->
    <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="rand/greetings.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you could use `object-fit: contain;` on your image.. if you don't mind about IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will keep an image horizontally aligned within a div (use the full page link and change the browser size to see the image change size)

```css
#wrap {
  border:1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#wrap > img {
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/city/1/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102444/how-to-fit-the-image-height-first-and-then-width-proportional-and-make-it-respon. Trying to make it respnsive in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width` or `height` to 100% but not both, this will keep the proportions of the image and allow it to scale.

```
<div style="float:right;"> <!-- img area -->
    <img style="width:100%;" src="rand/greetings.png"/>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

To prevent an image spilling out of your area vertically try setting a max-height in pixels on the image and image area:

```
<div style="float:right; max-height:100px;"> <!-- img area -->
    <img style="width:100%; max-height:90px;" src="rand/greetings.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the random image is a taller image? Wouldn't it go beyond the 'img area' height?

Comment: You could set a `max-height` defined in `px` on your image and image area to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep it simple, you can set this image as `background-image` and use `background-size:contain;`